# Find records having count > 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, having

I have a table containing duplicates of records. These duplicates are grouped in duplicate groups and also have an index (recordnumber) within the corresponding group. In the relevant table I have all records, even those which are not duplicates.

I need to select only those records, which have a minimum of 2 entries in a aduplicate group. so I used count, group by and having.

the issue is that I get strange result when doing so. The following screenshot shows all records including those with only one entry in a duplicate group. There are about 10k groups containing 2 or more duplicates

[image]

The issue is that as soon I uncomment the commented section, I only get 16 records instead of all with > 1 entries in a group and only groupid's 2 to 8...

[image]

does anybody see what I am missing here?

```
SELECT new_firstname AS firstname,
       new_lastname AS lastname,
       DubGroupID AS groupid,
       RecNumberInDupGroup AS recnr_ingroup
FROM [SOMETABLE]
WHERE BatchCheckJobID = '59aae39d7ee949fc8c9cce2a5efc2a5e'
  AND DubGroupID IN (SELECT COUNT(DubGroupID)
                     FROM [SOMETABLE]
                     GROUP BY DubGroupID
                     HAVING COUNT(DubGroupID) > 1)
ORDER BY groupid,
         recnr_ingroup ASC;
```

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Should be `and DubGroupID in (select DubGroupID FROM [SOMETABLE]`...

Comment: aargghh, you're right, missed it completely...thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You checking DubGroupID IN(but selecting count here). Do something as below-

```
......
AND DubGroupID IN (SELECT DubGroupID 
                 FROM [SOMETABLE]
                 GROUP BY DubGroupID
                 HAVING COUNT(DubGroupID) > 1)
.........
```

Answer (score 2):

This is too long for a comment (as it contains SQL), but couldn't the above be written as the below?

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT new_firstname AS firstname,
           new_lastname AS lastname,
           DubGroupID AS groupid,
           RecNumberInDupGroup AS recnr_ingroup,
           COUNT(DubGroupID) OVER (PARTITION BY DubGroupID) AS [Count]
    FROM SOMETABLE
    WHERE BatchCheckJobID = '59aae39d7ee949fc8c9cce2a5efc2a5e')
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE [Count] > 1;
```

That would return all rows where there is more than 1 row with the same value for `DubGroupID`, where `BatchCheckJobID` has a value of `'59aae39d7ee949fc8c9cce2a5efc2a5e'`.

Unlike your query using an `IN` this won't cause 2 scans of the table either.

Comment: Thank you very much...this woul be even better but I need to do it the other way unfortunately...but thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean "the other way" @MartinFelber? Using an `IN`? Why? if that is an requirement, you should be explaining it in your question.

Comment: I meant to use the query with the IN clause. this has a technical background in which I cannot use the "WITH" version unfortunately.

@Larnu Yes sorry, forgot to mention it

Comment: Why can you *not* use `WITH` @MartinFelber? CTEs were introduced in SQL Server 2005 (if I recall correctly, might be 2008) and are available in every supported version of SQL Server. If you can't use `WITH`, that suggests you're using a (very) old version of SQL Server; which if so should be tagged in your question as the volunteers here will *assume* you are using supported technology

Comment: I know CTE's but there are some limitations in a 3rd party API call which I have to use and which does not accept CTE's. And as I said, I am sorry for not mention this fact....sorry for that.